# Samba ADDC DNS with external DNS

Tags: samba

I want to run Samba ADDC. I have networks configured on router (linux with bind and isc-dhcp) whitch is managing some subnets (LAN / WAN / DMZ / etc.).

On one subnet I want to make ADDC, but I want to have some other devices in the same subnet.
I have name".subnet.intranet" for that subnet, and some devices inside. Samba ADDC had own DNS server, can I use both DNS? Do I need other or different subnet name for only ADDC? Do I need to make separated vlan and subnet for ADDC? I have IPcam, Printers, and some more non windows devices. Can it to be part of this domain (in the same subnet), or need I move it outside, or what do it right way?

Can someone explain me how is the right way to make network with "mixed" devices?

What happen when I move PC with ADDC outside company (.subnet.intranet) do I stil can login and work localy (login to domain acount and work on local documents in future I enable openVPN for samba shares and RDP)?

Curently Im using NT4 domain ant work ok, but I want to upgrade to ADDC.
All PC in subnet are win10pro or win11pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, AD has *nothing* to do with subnets or VLANs. Yes, there are a few AD features (such as 'sites') that care about subnet boundaries, but on the whole it really does not care about your network topology at all – it's all about domain names and TCP connectivity only. For example, we have ~twenty subnets that all contain machines in the same AD domain, and they all talk to the same AD DCs that are in their own "server" subnet. (And if you want, you can have multiple domains on the same subnet without any problems.)

Only the old NT4-style domains did care about VLANs and subnets (as they relied on NetBIOS for operations), but those have been obsolete for 20+ years – ever since Active Directory was introduced. There is nothing in Active Directory that relies on NetBIOS these days; DC Locator discovery is done purely through DNS.

Regarding DNS records: Yes, you can freely add whatever subdomains you want to your AD domain zone – as long as you don't modify the built-in stuff (e.g. the SRV records). Most AD-specific DNS entries actually are stored in a separate subdomain zone (_msdcs) anyway. So if you have `ad.intranet` as your AD domain, you can just open the "DNS Server" management console in Windows (or use samba-tool from Linux) and create `laptop.ad.intranet` regardless of whether it's an AD machine or not. You can even delegate whole subdomains (using 'NS' records) to a separate server.

Regarding DNS servers: The main AD domain needs to be served by Samba. You can use the built-in Samba DNS server if it works for you, and it is also possible to use the BIND9 DNS server (usually better performance) – Samba comes with a DLZ module that lets BIND read zones directly from Active Directory.

Your LAN hosts do not necessarily need to directly use the Samba DNS server; they can use any resolver as long as it knows how to find the AD domain. So you could, for example, have a central Unbound resolver that's configured to forward "ad.intranet" queries to Samba. (But it *has to* know how to resolve "ad.intranet" – the AD client devices can't just pull DNS data out of the void.)

Comment: To check if i good mean it. I could have lan1.intranet, lan2.intranet, etc for subnets. and example ad.company.com for ADDC ? And If I made routing, dhcp, vpn etc on router it will work. (my DHCP make DNS entry in router DNS for subnet domains, but ADDC entry made PDC). it is correct?

Comment: Yes, AD doesn't care about your non-AD domains; you can manage those in whatever way you want. In short, the only two requirements are that 1) clients can do DNS queries for their AD domain (nslookup) and 2) clients can make TCP/UDP connections to the DC.